# Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Find a constant c for which $P(|Z| ≥ c) = 0.1470$. Round the answer to two decimal places.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Find a constant c for which $P(|Z| ≥ c) = 0.1470$. Round the answer to two decimal places.

I am not sure what to do here. I thought of taking the inequality and splitting it into two inequalities, but I can't remember the rules that go with switching the less than and greater than signs. And I also don't know what to do with two different inequalities. Can someone explain this whole process in detail? I can't find similar examples in my book or online.

Comment: Remember that the distribution is symmetric about $0$.

Comment: i do remember that, but I'm still confused about how to set the problem up and solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(|Z|>c)$ means $P(Z>c)$ and $P(Z<-c)$ and each of those areas should be $0.0735$. The value for $c$ can be found in a Standard normal table, or you can use technology. I use the table and find a closest value $c$ of $1.45$. You have to know how to read a Standard normal table though.

Comment: can you show me how P(|Z|>c)P(|Z|>c) means P(Z>c)P(Z>c) and P(Z<−c)P(Z<−c)

Comment: @2316354654 What does $|z|>c$ mean normally? Shade this region on the real axis.  Then, try to see how the standard normal part of the argument works (to be clear, the first part of the argument requires no probability theory).

Comment: I think I'm forgetting my algebra. I thought it meant z > c, and -z > c, but I'm supposed to flip the > sign for -. I'm forgetting why. I kinda wanna see a proof of why.

Comment: and im not sure how to shad it on the real axis

Comment: also, if i chose to just memorize that rule, I am left with two probabilities. One gives me a negative answer, the other gives me a positive. How do I know which one to take to get c? wait i did it wrong

Comment: In Normal distribution $P(x>c)=P(x<-c)$